# how to enable GitHub Copilot in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, github, vscode-extensions, github-for-windows

I didn't know how to enable GitHub Copilot authorized users in the visual studio code, and I got a notification of an issue that the GitHub Copilot message couldn't connect to the server. Extension activation failed: User not authorized,I asked for his help in how to resolve this issue,thank you

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any solution? I have this problem too

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:
You’ve been added to the waitlist for the GitHub Copilot technical preview! No need to do anything else—we'll let you know when you can start using it. Just make sure your primary email address is up-to-date!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhYHC.png)

Comment: "We’re adding people as we have capacity, thanks for your patience and understanding." -> More information here https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/7707#discussioncomment-1644339 .

Comment: "Don’t have access yet? Sign up for the waitlist for your chance to try it out. GitHub will notify you once you have access." -> https://github.com/features/copilot/signup .

Answer (score -1):

If you have access already and received their email, You can try to close the Visual Studio code window and start it again.
**NB: Make sure you are connected to the internet.**